# How to change the size of UIButton using @IBInspectable property?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

My class for `UIButton`:

```
@IBDesignable class AttributedButton: UIButton {

    @IBOutlet private var widthLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    @IBInspectable override var isSelected: Bool {
    
        didSet {
        
            widthLayoutConstraint?.constant = isSelected ? 100 : 50
            borderColor = isSelected ? UIColor.lightGray : UIColor.white
        }
    }
}
```

and then when I change in storyboard the width inside `isSelected` property, it doesn't work... why?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure of adding `widthLayoutConstraint` as an IBOutlet inside the class? if the button is reusable, then the `widthLayoutConstraint` an IBOutlet

Comment: Yes, I am sure... button is not reusable... in the `UIViewController` there are 3 static buttons...

Comment: Is there any other way to increase the size of `UIButton`? Constraint is one of my ideas...

Comment: After trying to play around, it seems that editing the frame of the button won't appear on the storyboard  as it should...

Comment: If you try it (or you want to...), changing the width -for example- `    @IBInspectable var width: CGFloat = 50.0 {
        didSet {
            self.frame.size.width = self.width
        }
    }`, you will need to navigate to another class and reopen the storyboard to see the change.